# Scheduling tasks without windows task scheduler

Tags: java

How can i schedule a task like running batch file without using windows task scheduler? Can I do it with the help of some java code? All I can find is using windows pre-installed task scheduler, please help me regarding this.

Comment: can you specify the exact scenario... what tasks do you want to schedule??

Comment: I am trying to run a batch file which does copying of files. So, i want to schedule them without the scheduler.

Comment: so, you want the batch file(s) to run at the time you specify...?

Comment: yeah, i want to schedule them using some explicit code, preferably JAVA.

Comment: get an instance of runtime and call runtime.exec().. passing what you want to exec.. and for the time. you can get time from calender or any other mechanism and then do, if (currentTim.equals(thistime)) { put the code to get runtime instance and runtime.exec() } . I am not sure if this the right way though...

Comment: better you use TimerTask in java. Go through the example http://www.mkyong.com/java/jdk-timer-scheduler-example/

Comment: thanq X86 and Optimus, yours answer together i could do something, it was a good home work, gotta learn new things.

Answer (score 0):

You could try CRON from CygWin.
Of course, this is still some kind of scheduler, but as long as you told you want to «run a batch file which does copying of files», installing CygWin and scheduling the task at CRON should work.
Installation instructions [here](http://www.davidjnice.com/articles/cygwin_cron-service.html).